# WPF TreeView: WordWrap

Tags: wpf

I have this project that displays hierarchical data with huge amounts of text, and I'm transitioning from winforms to wpf, and with winforms treeview not wordwrapping out of the box I really wanna know how to do this in wpf. Is it possible to have Items in the TreeView use word wrapping, out of the box?

I've looped through a fair amount of threads and google results, but none got me any working method. ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="false" got me nowhere either.

If its not there, how would one approach the implementation? I'm quite new to wpf, so I'd appreciate a direction to push in.

Oh, and the framework is 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd have to bind the width of the root control of the treeview's node template to the actual width of the treeview itself.  So something like the following:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tv">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate TargetType={x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyToBind}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tv}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

You should also be able to set the width binding using a relative source, but I can't recall the syntax.

Usually these types of problems are solved by forcibly constraining the element inside of its parent element (even though it should technically already do that).   Just an idea. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Adam! Binding to ActualWidth does work, now I'm wondering how I set it to (ActualWidth - 5) - cant figure out the syntax. The construction I used to bind to TreeView was as follows: MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=ActualWidth}". It wont let me write 'Path=ActualWidth - 5' or similar; how do I go around that?

Comment: I don't believe you can do arithmetic like that directly in a binding. You'd have to include a converter.  See:  http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html